# How to prevent external USB drive icon appearing in launcher?

Tags: nautilus, launcher, usb-drive

When I attach a USB drive (or any external drive) an icon appears in the Launcher.

Is there a way to prevent the USB icon from showing in Launcher?

I know it is possible to **right-click** and select **Unlock from Launcher**, but this will not prevent it appearing again. I'm not sure, but probably because this will just blacklist the *uuid*, which might be different next time one connects the USB device.

So is there a way to prevent any drive or maybe any USB device from appearing in launcher?